# How do I implement vector reallocation?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am attempting to implement my own version of a C++ vector, but I'm having issues with my reallocation function when the size becomes equal to the capacity. Specifically, when the debugger reaches the delete line, I am given a heap corruption error stating that the application wrote to memory after the end of the heap buffer. Could someone give advice on why my approach is wrong? Please let me know if there is any other information needed that would be helpful in solving this issue.

EDIT: I have added all of my current code so that others can test the program and reproduce the issue.

Header file:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

template <class ItemType> class Vector{
    public:
        Vector();
        Vector(int capacity);
        int size();
        int capacity();
        bool is_empty();
        ItemType at(int index);
        void push(ItemType newItem);
        void printItems();
        ~Vector();

    private:
        int m_capacity; // number of items we can hold
        int m_size; // current number of items
        int m_unitSize; // size of one unit (used for arithmetic in indexing)
        ItemType* m_vectorPtr; // pointer to actual vector
        void reallocate(); // reallocates memory if array is filled

};

#endif
```

Implementations and testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
#include <assert.h>

// default constructor
template <class ItemType>
Vector<ItemType>::Vector()
:m_capacity(0), m_size(0) {
    m_unitSize = sizeof(ItemType);
    m_vectorPtr = nullptr;
}

// constructor with given number of items
template <class ItemType>
Vector<ItemType>::Vector(int capacity)
:m_size(0){
    int x = 1;
    while (x <= capacity) {
        x *= 2;
    }
    m_unitSize = sizeof(ItemType);
    m_capacity = x;
    m_vectorPtr = new ItemType[capacity];
}

// return total possible items
template <class ItemType>
int Vector<ItemType>::capacity() {
    return m_capacity;
}

// return current number of elements
template <class ItemType>
int Vector<ItemType>::size() {
    return m_size;
}

// return whether the vector is currently empty
template <class ItemType>
bool Vector<ItemType>::is_empty() {
    return m_size == 0;
}

// return the item at a given index
template<class ItemType>
ItemType Vector<ItemType>::at(int index) {
    return m_vectorPtr[index];
}

// reallocate the array if it becomes full
template <class ItemType>
void Vector<ItemType>::reallocate() {
    if (m_size >= m_capacity) {
        // allocate a new array twice the capacity
        m_capacity *= 2;
        ItemType* newVector = new ItemType[m_capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
            newVector[i] = m_vectorPtr[i];
        }
        delete[] m_vectorPtr;
        m_vectorPtr = newVector;
    }
}

// push an item onto the vector at the end
template<class ItemType>
void Vector<ItemType>::push(ItemType newItem) {
    if (m_size >= m_capacity) {
        // reallocate memory for the vector
        reallocate();
    }
    // push new item onto vector
    m_vectorPtr[m_size] = newItem;
    m_size++;
}

template <class ItemType>
void Vector<ItemType>::printItems() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
        std::cout << m_vectorPtr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <class ItemType>
Vector<ItemType>::~Vector() {
    delete[] m_vectorPtr;
}

// test here
int main() { 

    // initialize a vector
    int startingCapacity = 3;

    Vector<int> testVector(startingCapacity);

    assert(testVector.capacity() == 4 &&
           testVector.size() == 0 &&
           testVector.is_empty() == true);

    // add two items to the vector
    testVector.push(3);
    testVector.push(7);

    assert(testVector.capacity() == 4 &&
           testVector.size() == 2 &&
           testVector.is_empty() == false);

    // print the two items
    testVector.printItems();

    // add past capacity to test reallocate
    testVector.push(5);
    testVector.push(8);
    testVector.push(6);

    assert(testVector.capacity() == 8 &&
        testVector.size() == 5 &&
        testVector.is_empty() == false);

    testVector.printItems();

    std::cout << "All test cases passed." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably go out of bounds of your allocated memory. But without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be impossible to tell anything for certain.

Comment: You have to reallocate before you change `m_size` because the `for` loop will be incorrect if `m_size > m_capacity` and you'll access `m_vectorPtr` past its size. And make sure the new capacity is big enough `(m_capacity *= 2) > m_size`

Comment: Based on my implementation of push, reallocate will always be called when size == capacity, right? So the access in the for loop shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Looks ok if you construct with capacity, but your default constructor starts with `:m_capacity(0), m_size(0) {` and doubling 0 , `0 *= 2;`, do not help. So on the second push you'll get heap coruption because your `m_size` will be 1 but capacity and still 0. Just make sure `m_capacity` is not 0 before allocation, ok?

Comment: That's a good catch, I'll be sure to fix it. However, since the vector I am testing with does not use the default constructor, I don't see how this could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reallocate before you change `m_size` because the `for` loop will be incorrect if `m_size > m_capacity` and you'll access `m_vectorPtr` past its size. And make sure the new capacity is big enough `(m_capacity *= 2) > new_size`

```
template <class ItemType>
void Vector<ItemType>::reallocate(size_t new_size) {
    if (new_size > m_capacity) {
        // allocate a new array twice the capacity
        if (m_capacity == 0)
            m_capacity = 10;
        while (m_capacity < new_size)
            m_capacity *= 2;
        ItemType* newVector = new ItemType[m_capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
            newVector[i] = m_vectorPtr[i];
        }
        delete[] m_vectorPtr;
        m_vectorPtr = newVector;
    }
}
```

And here sample `push_back` method reallocating before changing `m_size`:

```
void push_back(ItemType item) {
    reallocate(m_size + 1);
    m_vectorPtr[m_size] = item;
    m_size++;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e75d7dd2b7dadb87)</kbd>

#### UPDATE

You have a small bug in the constructor **NOT**:

```
m_vectorPtr = new ItemType[capacity];
```

but

```
m_vectorPtr = new ItemType[m_capacity];
```

because `capacity` is the requested one, not the power of two you want (3, not 4 in your test).

Comment: It took me a while, but I finally understand the solution you proposed, which works. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I was trying to use the debugger to trace through my error to see exactly when `m_size > m_capacity` was occurring, and I could not find this instance. So while your solution makes sense, I'm still not sure where exactly my example vector is going wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have a small bug in the constructor not `m_vectorPtr = new ItemType[capacity];` but `m_vectorPtr = new ItemType[m_capacity];`, because `capacity` is 3, not 4.